# Ajax GET request works on Chrome but not Firefox or Safari

Tags: html, ajax, http, express

The following code works fine in Chrome. The route for this get prints out the reportOrder to the terminal. (This is not the final goal but just for testing to make sure the data is received properly). If the request is made in Chrome the server receives the stringified JSON and prints it to the terminal. If the request is made in Safari or Firefox, the server returns a 404 error.

```
if(formready){
       document.getElementById("invalidform").innerHTML = "";
       var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                };
                console.log(this.status);
            };
        xhttp.open("GET", "/submit/"+JSON.stringify(reportOrder), true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("invalidform").innerHTML = "<p style='color: red'>Oops! Please correct all fields marked in red.</p>";
    }
```

I've read a few things about ajax requests being finicky in different browsers but don't understand why the server would return a 404.

Just in case this is helpful here is the route:

```
app.get("/submit/:data", function(req, res){
   var rawFormData = req.params.data;
   var formData = JSON.parse(rawFormData);
   console.log(formData);
});
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of `reportOrder` which causes `404`? Also, to pass parameters in `GET` URL, it is better to serialize using parameter format, such as using `jQuery.param(...)`.

Comment: On second thought. I think you are right and it has something to do with the string that is being passed. I still don't completely understand why that would make it different per browser unless each browser is somehow sending a different string than Chrome.

Comment: Can you open debugger of Firefox or Safari and check what is the URL in `GET` request? Maybe there are some policy in your Firefox/Safari which will alter URL automatically.

Comment: So, Chrome seems to automatically put escape characters in the url. The stringify function is just removing white space. Safari and Firefox send it as is according to the debugger get requests. Chrome on the other hand, puts in escape characters.

Comment: OK. It seems you need to escape the characters manually and then concatenate them in the URL?

Comment: I guess so. Is there an easy way to de-serialize it from the jQuery.param format back into JSON format on server side?

Comment: When I use jQuery.param the GET request gets through on all browsers, but the format is going to require me to make a custom parser if I can't use jQuery server side.

Comment: You don't have to write a custom parser, Express has already done that and expose as `req.query`. Please refer to my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass parameters in GET URL, it is better to serialize using parameter format, such as using `jQuery.param(...)` (alias: `$.param(...)`). OP mentioned that "When I use jQuery.param the GET request gets through on all browsers."

To read the parameters in server side, it's not necessary to write a custom parser. Express has already parsed them and expose as [req.query](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query).

For example, if the GET request is sent to URL `/submit?a=42&b=88`, then in server side `req.query` would be an object containing property `a` and `b`:

```
app.get('/submit', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.query); // { a: '42', b: '88' }
  res.status(200).end();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need full path in get request url.

Comment: Why does it work in Chrome without the full path? I added the full path, and it works in Chrome but not in Safari or Firefox still.